# how can we add a custom checkbox field on snap-ins pre chat page

Tags: snap-ins

Currently only few fields are showing out of the box that can be added to snap-ins pre chat page. How can we add any custom field like checkbox or URL to pre chat page of snap-ins chat

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i have created a custom checkbox field that i want to add on pre chat page of snap-ins but on setup in which we add case and contact fields for Pre-chat page this custom checkbox field is not showing up and i am not able to add... is there any way in which custom fields with any data type can be added out of the box or through code to the pre-chat form?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications.